# Id declaration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, relationship

I have some entity classes and i have a question because I want to clear it in my mind. In case of `@ManyToOne` relationship where I insert for example `@JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderId")`, shall I remove the primitive `private Long cardHolderId`? Because I had a discussion and a programmer explained to me that I can avoid declaring. But if I avoid it I can not use it in test cases like services.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "issueDate")
    private Date issueDate;

    @Column(name = "expireDate")
    private Date expireDate;

    @Column(name = "elasticDate")
    private Date elasticDate;

    @Column(name = "pin")
    private Long pin;

    @Column(name = "isValid")
    private Boolean isValid;

    @Column(name = "isUsed")
    private Boolean isUsed;

    @Column(name = "isPin")
    private Boolean isPin;

    @Column(name = "cardCategoryId")
    private Long cardCategoryId;

    @Column(name = "hasNumberOfVisits")
    private Boolean hasNumberOfVisits;

    @Column(name = "numberOfVisits")
    private Long numberOfVisits;

    @Column(name = "isBlackListed")
    private Boolean isBlackListed;

    @Column(name = "cardHolderId")
    private Long cardHolderId;

    //Check Relationships

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardCategoryId")
    private CardCategory cardCategory;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHolderId")
    private CardHolder cardHolder;

    @Column(name = "companyGroupId")
    private Long companyGroupId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyGroupId")
    private CompanyGroup companyGroup;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
    private List<AccessControlSubject> accessControlSubjects = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
    private List<Card2Role> card2Roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardHistoryId")
    private CardHistory cardHistory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleCard")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sharedCardId")
    private PatrolSharedCard sharedCard;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productionWorkId")
    private PrdWork productionWork;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productionWorkHitsId")
    private PrdWorkHits productionWorkHits;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
    private List<VisitorCardHistory> visitorCardHistories = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Why not? create a getter that does `return this.companyGroup.getId()`. WHy would you need an additional field. It will only complicate the matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Deinum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it and use the id from the referred entity :

```
this.getCardHolder().getId()
```